# What will be Scroll Event Type in TypeScript and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I know we can use event listener and work with ScrollEvent.

But suppose following method:

```
handleScroll =(event:any):void=>{
const target = event.target;
// further code goes her
}
```

I want to use event type instead of any so what should be its type?

Comment: Try inlining your event handler, `<Component scroll={event => event.}` and see what type inference serves you up ;)

Answer (score 3):

if you aim to catch the mouse-wheel scroll event then you can use this type.

```
handleScroll = (event: WheelEvent): void =>
```

Comment: User can drag scrollbar and do mouse scroll as well.

Comment: From _React TypeScript Cheatsheet_'s List of Events (https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/#list-of-event-types): "Scrolling on a mouse wheel or similar input device. (Note: wheel event should not be confused with the scroll event)"

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing this in React then you would use

```
handleScroll = (event: Event):void => {
  const target = event.target;
  // further code goes here
}
```

If you using React and the scrolling is being done in a `<div>` then you would use

```
handleScroll = (event: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>):void => {
  const target = event.target;
  // further code goes here
}
```

If the event is occuring on another type of element (and using React) then you should substitute that for `<HTMLDivElement>`.

As per a comment I wrote below another post here, you should not confuse `wheel` and `scroll` events.